# We should be able to initiate a search using the mouse

Tags: feature-request, search, user-interface, user-experience, accessibility

After entering some text in the search box, I am not able to use the mouse to search: only the  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  key works to initiate the search.

There is a magnifying glass button in the left-hand side of the search box, but it is not clickable:

[image]

Please enable the option to operate the search box using the mouse as well as the keyboard. It will be very useful for us.

Comment: this icon is simply a background image; should add a submit button

Comment: The use-case being where you cut and paste search terms into the box? Otherwise, your finger is .. you know .. _right next to the button you need to push_.

Comment: @TimPost even then I use keyboard shortcuts instead of my mouse. However, after quite a bit of feedback from computer illiterate users to the project I'm working on, we also changed the icon to be clickable. It's apparently confusing to these people when they can't click on a button.

Comment: All of the buttons on my keyboard are clickable.

Comment: However, and somewhat unrelated, one must applaud the skill that Vignesh has demonstrated with [carefully-timed screenshots](http://i.stack.imgur.com/56ZJY.jpg). Good show sir, good show.

Comment: @TimPost Thank you...! I hope you are not kidding me..

Comment: Should be posted to MSE, I guess... *and UX.se*

Comment: @Stijn Why should we worry about computer illiterate users on stackoverflow? If anything, it would make sense to do *more* to keep them away.

Comment: @ivarni So you wouldn't mind if this was implemented on all the other sites in the network, but on SO it should not be implemented? A feature request being posted on MSO does not mean it is only for MSO.

Comment: Perhaps we should just move this discussion to MSE then so this entire discussion about "not on SO!" can be trashed. It's a useless discussion anyway, it's not like it would negatively impact those who do not wish to use the feature.

Comment: @Stijn when it's posted on MSO I assume it's about SO, yes.

Comment: @ivarni and that's where you're wrong. Users are allowed to post on the Meta of the site they frequent and feel comfortable with, they do not need to go to MSE.

Comment: @Stijn Have I tried to stop you from posting? I've disagreed with a feature request, and I believe I am allowed to do that.

Comment: @ivarni that's not what I said? It was on your assumption that a post on MSO is about SO.

Comment: Why not just make the magnifying glass clickable? I understand it's not clickable atm because it's a background image, but that's fixable... Those who don't like it, don't have to use it. Also, it wouldn't affect visibility or design of the site at all.

Comment: @TimPost Yes, I would call that a common use case. But another one would be mobile, where you often have no actual `Enter` button, but just a button that closes the keyboard. You are then expected to click the button. Of course, I've never looked at SE on mobile, so maybe it's different there.

Comment: I'd point out that there's a competing standard for what that magnifying glass should do (if anything -- personally, I read it as a label, not a "button"). In webkit, an input of type "search" with the "results" attribute will show a magnifying glass at the left, but clicking it shows a list of previous searches. I think the convention is that a search button, if present, is to the *right* of the input.

Comment: Who uses the search field anyway?  Haven't I read many meta posts about how Google is much more efficient?

Comment: @trlkly: I always access SE via mobile, it works fine without any issues. This question is about the desktop interface.

Comment: **Note: I did a rollback because the previous edit by OP was invalid.**

Comment: What if someone has reduced mobility in their arms and can't easily move between keyboard/mouse? Or what if they're just feeling particularly lazy and only want to use the mouse to highlight some text, copy/paste and then initiate their search? This is a no-brainer decision to anyone with any sense of good usability.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure how much we *need* something like this, but I like to fix things, so here's a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/4856/click-to-search).

It just adds a simple "search" button to the top bar because the magnifying glass that is part of the search field appears to be part of its background or is otherwise inaccessible for modification. It works fine on all sites I've tested (including [Ask Ubuntu](//askubuntu.com), which I was concerned about due to its different top bar design).

Following bjb568's suggestion, I've removed the "search" placeholder in the field to prevent redundancy.

[image: Search link]

---

I've updated it to use HTML5 `localStorage`, so you can set whether you prefer a link format (shown above) or, as per Cody Gray's suggestion, a button:

[image: Search button]

The reason why I didn't do this originally is because the design for a button varies largely between Stack Exchange sites, so you run into issues like this:

[image: MSE search button]

Of course, since it's using `localStorage`, it's on a per-site basis (as I've mentioned above), so you can set your preference for each.

To reset your preferences, look for a link in the footer called "reset":

[image: Reset preferences]

Comment: The search button looks separate from the search field.

Comment: Sure, but at least move the button text closer to the search box, or make it look like…a button. Right now, it looks like other text on the title bar and completely independent of that search box. Like the "review" link, it looks like something that will take you to a search page, not invoke a search based on the text you've entered.

Comment: @CodyGray Technically, it will, but I get your point: I tried a button at first, but it looks very odd on the topbar and button styling varies from site to site. I wanted to make it look like it actually belongs there so that it's not too much of an eyesore, but I can change it if enough people want it (the source is there, also, so you can modify it to your liking). I could move it closer, but I'd have to modify the search field's padding, which could mess up the topbar entirely. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @CodyGray I've updated it with an option to use a button rather than a link: tell me what you think.

Comment: Better, but saying "search" twice looks awkward.

Comment: @bjb568 True: fixed. I also added a reset button so that you can change your option and edits ar enow applied immediately (no need to manually refresh).

Comment: You could make it a button but also call `.css('padding', '2px')` or something on it to remedy some of the weirdness

Comment: @Doorknob That should come standard. MSE buttons are horocious.

Comment: This is a great solution, fixes the "not on MY SO!" complaints and still allows those that want to install it to have a button.  You have only the "..." and "PROFIT!!!" left! :)

Comment: @paqogomez - it would be easier to *remove* the button with a userscript than add one ;)

Comment: MSE buttons are fantastic.

Comment: @misterManSam, I'm sure it would also be easier to remove the smile from the Mona Lisa than it would be to add one also. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Even as a person who up until this moment had no clue it wasn't a button and would never choose to leave the keyboard to grab a mouse, navigate, and press a button that could have been activated with a simple finger movement, it's a valid feature request for the entire exchange.

If nothing else is done to accommodate this then the magnifier should be removed considering it's a design fu given all other sites that *do*, AFAIF, have it as a button thus creating a muscle memory/UI problem.

We don't have to cater to computer illiterate users but coming from a CAD background, where it's possible to get functionality from either the keyboard or mouse, it's more of a user preference of interaction. The vast majority of drafters I know use the keyboard shortcuts and it's assumed this is the faster way. However, I've ran across a few that are speed demons with the mouse. It would be unreasonable for Autodesk, for example, to say mouse users are computer illiterate and remove support for it.

All this leads to the fact that we shouldn't be in the business of validating a user's preference of interaction especially in the case of a feature that is pretty standard elsewhere. If we are going to imitate a design feature here it should be consistent with other sites that do the same. It also seems like a fairly easy feature to implement.

Comment: I agree, but I will say that, after this posting, I've been trying to click the magnifying glass on some search fields on other sites that I've seen and, surprisingly, many of them behave exactly in the same way they do here (i.e. they don't do anything), but that's just a cursory observation.

Comment: @AstroCB, that is surprising. When I looked around before posting, and again after your comment, I was unable to find one. Granted I chose larger corporate sites. The main difference I see is SO's is more of a hint; perhaps it should be removed when the text changes to avoid confusion. The fact it pointlessly hangs around is weird.

Answer (score -22):

Remove the magnifying glass. Don't add a button. I don't like buttons. I don't like magnifying glasses.

Comment: Have you considered [my comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269395/we-should-be-able-to-initiate-a-search-using-the-mouse#comment82625_269395)?

Comment: Or using magnifying glasses against insects?

Comment: @Stijn Yes, we're programmers not idiot-users here, so our UI can be more powerful than easy to use.

Comment: I assume a feature like this would be rolled out network-wide.

Comment: It doesn't have to be.

Comment: @Stijn: We _hope_ that SO users and "computer illiterate users" are still disjoint sets.

Comment: How will illiterate users know that it is a search box without a magnifying glass? Judging by some time I spent recently in the review queue, we have a *lot* of illiterate users that we need to accomodate.

Comment: @CodyGray I think it's more important to accommodate those with ban rights to ban those suckers!

Comment: +1 I don't like buttons either, except only when they're flashy.

Comment: "i don't like x" is not a reason to remove x. you should update your answer with your reasoning.

Comment: @sgroves What? It's a perfectly good reason. We're talking about UX here, it isn't like there's much fact to say.

Comment: Delete your account. Don't create another one. I don't like your account. I don't like new ones. Valid reasoning, right?

Comment: @Doorknob I'm just saying what I prefer and gaging how much the community agrees. Nobody said I was presenting an argument.

Comment: @bjb568 posting JUST what you prefer without posting a reason is **useless**. everyone has a different opinion. one person's opinion out of a sea of opinions is meaningless. you've got to provide reasons to try and convince people to agree with you. otherwise your answer is just a waste of space. i'm not trying to be mean.

Comment: @sgroves This is meta, quit complaining about "wasting space" on opinions.

Comment: @bjb568 you asked, so i explained. something can still be a waste of space on meta (you just might not agree) :P

Comment: @bjb568 "We're talking about UX here, it isn't like there's much fact to say." Try that statement over at ux.se dude.