# Why isn't there a search button in the search bar?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search, top-bar, search-box

I expected a search button inside the search bar, which has the same function as the search button in the result page, or a magnifier icon as the search button (that appears on the right side after the is text entered).

[image: Instead, there is nothing to click on to activate search for the current search bar.]

Imagine an user like me entering some text into the search bar by the left hand, then I want to start searching by pressing the Enter key in the keyboard. But at that moment my right hand is still holding the mouse.

When I need to search for something, in most cases, the moment is viewing some content that I can't understand. As it isn't typing, my right hand usually hold the mouse for scrolling the page.

Let's see how Google handles this problem. When I start searching from an empty start page, there is no search button.

[image]

Then when I entered the searching result page, the search button appears because more content shows up. If I want to go searching further, I will select some words by mouse first, then copy and paste it into the search bar, and click the search button.

[image]

And here is a demo of my expectation.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ps-relative {
    width: 60%;
    position: relative !important;
}
.s-input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .6em .7em;
    border: 1px solid #bbc0c4;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0);
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: inherit;
    line-height: 1.15384615;
}
.s-input.s-input__search:placeholder-shown {
    padding-left: 32px;
}
.top-bar .searchbar .s-input {
    border-color: #bbc0c4;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #3b4045;
}
.s-input__search:placeholder-shown ~ .s-input-icon.s-input-icon__search {
    right: auto;
    left: .7em;
    color: #bbc0c4;
}
.svg-icon:not(.native) * {
    fill: currentColor;
}
.s-input-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: .7em;
    margin-top: -9px;
}
.s-input-icon.s-input-icon__search {
    right: .5em;
    left: auto;
    color: #66ccff;
}
.s-input__search:placeholder-shown ~ .s-input-icon{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.s-input__search ~ .s-input-icon:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="ps-relative">
  <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search…" value="" autocomplete="off" maxlength="240" class="s-input s-input__search js-search-field " aria-label="Search" aria-controls="top-search" data-controller="s-popover" data-action="focus->s-popover#show" data-s-popover-placement="bottom-start">
  <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon s-input-icon s-input-icon__search iconSearch" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" onclick="alert('Search')"><path d="M18 16.5l-5.14-5.18h-.35a7 7 0 1 0-1.19 1.19v.35L16.5 18l1.5-1.5zM12 7A5 5 0 1 1 2 7a5 5 0 0 1 10 0z"></path></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: there used to be a button [at the right side](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384767/578411) but only with a magnifier image.

Comment: Probably because there is more stuff in the top nav than in the body of the results page.

Comment: Keyyboard navigation.

Comment: @Ḿűỻịgǻṇạcểơửṩᛗ, Why? It's SO. You bing copy and past to mouse button and you are ready for programming, answering, and  asking.

Comment: Additional question - why is there "Ask a question" button *in the search*? 1. There is already one on top 2. Searching and asking a question are usually *opposite* of one another.

Comment: To make room for Products, Usecases and... some other link i can't recall the name of.

Comment: If your right hand is on the mouse, isn't your right thumb mere inches away from the numpad enter key?

Comment: @user400654 if you *have* a numeric pad on your keyboard. Some elect for smaller keyboards without one. Also, even if you *do* have a numeric pad, you might not have your right hand immediately next to your keyboard. Right now, I've got my keyboard and mouse on two different planes. No, it's not uncomfortable, it's actually better than having them next to each other for my current seating arrangement.

Comment: If you don’t have a numpad, the other enter key is on the right side. Same difference.

Comment: If you’re already using only your left hand to type and are already hitting keys on the far right of the keyboard with your left hand, how hard is it to go a quarter inch further?

Comment: What if your hand is not next to the main Enter key? Case in point, you want to click the search bar (can't activate it easily otherwise) -> paste by pressing Ctrl+V (also the easiest) -> search...but there is no easy way to either click a search with the mouse or with your left hand, since it's *literally* on the opposite side of the main Enter key. I can't really understand the reluctance of having the UI work correctly. What's the problem of including an action button for the functionality you want people to use?

Comment: Just have an `Enter` key on [both sides of the keyboard](https://www.keyboardco.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/DSCF3661.jpg) @user400654 ;) (I don't have one of those keyboards, that would be weird.)

Comment: I mean, if you're typing with just you left hand, presumably you're moving that hand across the whole keyboard anyway to reach L. Why not do that also for the enter key? (my point in all of this is you're argument is weak... there's certainly better arguments as to why a form should have a submit button...)

Comment: [regression?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269395/we-should-be-able-to-initiate-a-search-using-the-mouse/269453#269453)

Comment: **PLEASE ADD A SEARCH BUTTON. NOT IMPLEMENTING A SEARCH BUTTON IS A HUGE DESIGN FLAW!** (Think also about people who've only one hand, or even no hands at all!) Sorry for CAPS.